# <h1> allows only 12px margin-bottom, then makes my page float left

Tags: css, margin

If my css code is:

```
h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
    font-size: 2em; 
    margin-bottom:12px;
}
```

everything is ok as what I expect. but if my `margin-bottom` is greater than 12px, then my page floats a little to left.
I am using Chrome last version as of today. Also I am using Meyer's reset.css last version (v2.0)

What issue should I solve? Can you guide me please?

Comment: You'll need to post a more complete code example. jsFiddles help too.

Comment: Have you confirmed the issue is still present *without* reset.css?

Comment: without reset.css, whole structure gets stranger, also cross browser ability will be lost right? I don't want to use css hacks that w3c won't approve

Comment: I can't seem to recreate your problem.. http://jsfiddle.net/SA8ZN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that increasing the margin to more than 12 pixels would make the entire page unable to vertically fit in the browser, thus triggering the scrollbar to appear on the right, which will cause the entire page to shift a bit to the left (if you have centered the content)?